# Why don't work inline this: new List<string>().AddRange(...);?

Tags: c#, list

I try to use inline this:

```
var firstSizeColumns = new List<string>().AddRange(_alwaysShowProperty);
```

but a had error:

> Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed variable.

I knew that it must be in two lines. Simple:

```
var firstSizeColumns = new List<string>();
firstSizeColumns.AddRange(_alwaysShowProperty);
```

Comment: The error message is telling you exactly why it doesn't work.  What don't you understand about the error message?

Comment: Servy, Ok. Why intellisense suggests to choose then this and other extension methods?

Comment: Because it's a member of a list.  Intellisense will show you all members of the object when you ask it what members an object has.

Comment: @YanLinkin: Intellisense doesn't care about the entire line of code, it only cares about the word you're appending to. If you type `var myInt = DateTime.Now. ` you will still get the option of `ToString()` even though you're clearly wanting to assign an int. It would be a really bad idea for Intellisense to only show you what it **thinks** you want to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`AddRange` is a method with a **`void` return type**. Therefore you cannot assign the result to a variable.

Use `List`'s following constructor instead:

```
var collection = new List<string>(_alwaysShowProperty);
```

Comment: Not my DV, but perhaps it's because you're answering a question where the error message literally tells the OP what the problem is and they were too lazy to read it?

Comment: Note that you could create your own `MyList` wrapper class which enables operator chaining (by changing every `void` method to `return this;` instead). But that would require using a custom class for all lists, which may not be worth it in the long run.

Comment: @DavidG - I agree with that part but the reason I answered at all is because OP thinks it has to be in the two lines specified after the error, but a different constructor can solve it.

Comment: @GiladGreen If you'd like to share some related piece of information that you think someone might find interesting, but that isn't actually answering the question, the appropriate way to do that is to post a comment, not to post an answer.

Comment: @DaviG, I read this message but don't understand why intellisence try to suggest me this method.

Comment: @YanLinkin Don't rely on IntelliSense to debug your code, that's going to lead to laziness. All IntelliSense will do is suggest possible methods, it's not going to tell you how to use them. It's up to you to figure that out.

Comment: @Servy: The code provided by Gilad solves the problem at hand (without changing the intention of the code), and is therefore an answer to the problem. I do think that a bit more explanation is warranted (to help OP understand his mistake), but that's a quality issue rather than an issue with the validity of it as an answer.

Comment: @DavidG "it's not going to tell you how to use them. It's up to you to figure that out." and therefore I ask how it uses!)

Comment: @Flater The OP's code solves the problem at hand.  The OP was asking for an explanation of *the solution they had already found*.  An answer with an alternate solution isn't answering that question, it's just a tangential piece of information.  Again, that's fine as a comment, but it's not an answer.

Comment: @YanLinkin Yes, and you're figuring out that by posting to SO instead of researching this yourself. So yes, laziness is still the correct word I'm afraid. Did you google the error message? Did you look at the definition of `AddRange` for example? These things you should have done before coming here.

Comment: @David of cource first what I can do: it research, when I cannot found this error description in my context I ask this question this. Can you prompt where it is possible to look the specification for example for "addrange"?

Comment: @YanLinkin You're literally just asking me to Google "AddRange" for you now? Wow... I'm sure you can figure that out for yourself...

Comment: @DavidG its common answer. Not laziness to give you such answers and to learn me what intellisence just offers option under data type instead of just explaining?) It takes away a lot of time

Comment: @YanLinkin Sorry, but it's not common at all. I'm not discussing this any more as you are clearly not interested in improving yourself as a developer but prefer to rely on this site to answer simple questions.

Comment: @DavidG Ok, thanks for your answer, maybe I need to read the specification in the beginning before asking a question this.